# $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) not working

Tags: magento-1.6, tierprice

I have a website and few days before it was working fine. But suddenly it stopped showing Price in catalog page and product page.

In product page it is using this code snippet:

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone');
```

And in catalog page it is using

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

Anyone who can help. Its an urgent issue.

Comment: Have You change anything in catalog.xml or local.xml?

Comment: No, not from this two XML files and even not anything related to price.

Comment: What changes were made around the time the price stopped displaying?

Comment: Nothing much. We were using Sweet Tooth Rewards module. I have disabled it removed the required code.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet @GauravAgrawal?

Comment: @ArjenMiedema In my case it was because of Sweet Tooth Rewards module, I have removed all the entries from sweet tooth tables from database and then it started working.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal thanks. Could you write your solution as an answer, so we can mark this as solved. Thanks.